# Check IQueryable<T> Has Database Source using Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I am writing a Pager so that all my Queries (either DB or List Based) can use the same logic.

this seems to work correctly for functions like `StartsWith` when the data type is a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` but when the query comes from a DB Store (EF) it complains as i am setting the `StringComparison` property (EF does not implement the method signature with `StringComparision`)

What I have done is write 2 seperate functions 1 for normal list (with `StringComparison` and one for a DB Connected Query

My Question is: What is the best way to see if the Query is from a Data Store (without actually referencing the EF Modules as i dont want to be tied to EF).

This is what i currently have that works:

```
bool _queryConnectedToData=query.Provider.GetType().Namespace.ToLower().Contains("system.data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ObjectContext` to accomplish this

```
ObjectContext.GetObjectType(query.GetType());
```

For entity this will return your type of Entity, and with a list it'll still return your `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

It is tied to `System.Data.Entity`, but if you don't want it tied to that then inject it through an interface.

Comment: Will give it a try.

Comment: Just an update when its a `List<T>` it will return a type of `System.Linq.EnumerableQuery` not List. But you pointed me in the right directly. thanks so much